# Bug when converting string to integer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6, parseint

Hey guys I have a problem with parsing Strings in Javascript.
I have a big Number (162778063615164416) as a string. This is how a userID of discord looks like.
Now I'm trying to convert it to a Number but it always returns the wrong value.

Run the Snippet to see it.

```js
var qs = 'querySelector',
    qsa = 'querySelectorAll';
document[qs]('input').addEventListener('input', event => {
  var val = event.target.value;
  document[qsa]('td')[0][qs]('input').value = parseInt(val);
  document[qsa]('td')[1][qs]('input').value = Number(val);
  document[qsa]('td')[2][qs]('input').value = eval(val);
})
```

```html
<table style="border: solid 1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"><input value="162778063615164416" style="width:98%; text-align: center"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>parseInt()</th>
      <th>Number()</th>
      <th>eval()</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="parse" style="text-align: center" value="162778063615164400" disabled></td>
      <td><input id="number" style="text-align: center" value="162778063615164400" disabled></td>
      <td><input id="eval" style="text-align: center" value="162778063615164400" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I used three different methods to do the same thing and they all return wrong values. The output values should be the same as the input value.
Anyone know, how to convert strings with this length to numbers?

I'm using the [Discord API](https://discord.js.org/) for Node.js to create a selfbot. The user send a message to a channel and the programm should read the userID to identify the only one person to which it should reply. I can't write the ID in the programm code, because its dynamic: I wanted to pack it into a .exe, that other people (people which don't know JavaScript or don't want to install Node.js) can use it too to send embeds and do other cool stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

> The MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant has a value of 9007199254740991

---

You should ask yourself why you are converting it to a number so. Do you want to compare them? You can compare `Strings`. You want to look for special values? You can use Regexp over `Strings`.

Comment: Thanks. I've never knew there's a max save integer. I think I'll try to compare it with strings

Comment: It worked! Now I use the regexp `/\d{18}/g` to make sure it's only the integer and then I compare it with the ID if the message. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**use parseFloat(); it will give result in exponential**

Or

You can use a JavaScript lib called BigInteger.js for the purpose.it is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allows arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations.This lib can be download from this link.Like var largeNumber = bigInt("75643564363473453456342378564387956906736546456235345"); You can find documentation of lib here https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

## Copied

Comment: var a = parseFloat("10000000000000000"); like

Comment: Thank you guy. Exact the thing I asked but I'll try to validate them now first with a regexp and then only compare the strings (see @Grégory NEUT answer )

Answer (score 0):

It's bigger then max safe integer

Use float type

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER > 162778063615164416)
```